# what kind of type is BorderThickness?

Tags: wpf, calendar, border

I have a calendar and I want to set the border of the day in some color according to some conditions. For that I use a converter.

However, when the converter return 2, the broder is not shown, but if I don't use the converter and I put the "2" manually, the the border is visible.

I try to return a (int)2 value and "2" as string, but the problem persists.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can easily see in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.borderthickness.aspx) it's of type [`Thickness`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness.aspx).

Comment: where `Thickness` itself comes from 4 doubles http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness.aspx